# Using the "ı" character in place of "I" to refer to self - why?

Tags: discussion, questions, internationalization

I've noticed that a few question-askers recently (such as [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566754/dynamically-class-creating-by-using-java-reflection-java-lang-classnotfoundexcep)) use the `"ı"` character to refer to themselves, where one would normally use `"I"`.

(this character is more noticiable in the fixed-width font, so I used the backticks).

Does anyone know what is behind this? Is it an internationalization thing? Is this an idiom common in some part of the world?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's the dreaded [lowercase Turkish "I"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I), the bane of all i18n developers.

It's just a lowercase "i", but in the Turkish alphabet, it can be dotless.  I can only assume that those people are using Turkish keyboards/regional settings.

Comment: It's not a lowercase 'i', but a lowercase 'I'. In Turkish, `I` is to `ı` as `İ` is to `i`. The two letters in the upper- and lowercase forms are considered independent letters despite their similar appearance. In some ways it makes sense, but they didn't do it for the letter `j` (i.e. having a dotted-j majuscule).

Answer (score 5):

The poster is Turkish. He has his keyboard set to Turkish and is not using the shift key. Edited and replaced all `ı` s with `I` s.

Comment: See also http://www.howtosayinturkish.com/contents/alphabet/